# Copy the last populated row in a Google Sheet to a different spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I'm new to programming and would really appreciate some help.

I have two different spreadsheets, one named Database (this is where we put all the details) and the other is named Checklist, both have 1 worksheet each named Sheet1.

Now, what I wanted to do is to get the last populated row from the Database spreadsheet into the Checklist spreadsheet.

I know a formula like:

```
=FILTER('Sheet 2'!A:A , ROW('Sheet 2'!A:A) =MAX( FILTER( ROW('Sheet 2'!A:A) , NOT(ISBLANK('Sheet 2'!A:A)))))
```

This gets the last populated row, but this only works within one spreadsheet and doesn't work when I'm working on two different spreadsheets.

How can I get this formula to work with 2 different spreadsheets?

Thank you so much

Comment: That formula only provides the last value in column A. Is that what you want, or do you want the entire row?

Comment: Hi @Diego I only want to get the last value, but I can't seem to do it using two different spreadsheets

Answer (score 1):

To access data from another spreadsheet, you can use `IMPORTRANGE()` ([documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en)). I suggest you create a new sheet in your Checklist spreadsheet and import the sheet you need from Database into it. Then you'll be able to use your formula.

1. In Checklist, create a new sheet called "[IMPORTED] Database" (or something like that)
2. In cell A1 of "[IMPORTED] Database", enter `=IMPORTRANGE("database_spreadsheet_url", "Sheet1!A:Z")` (modify the range to be what you actually need)
3. Now adjust your formula for getting the last value to be `=FILTER('[IMPORTED] Database'!A:A, ROW('[IMPORTED] Database'!A:A)=MAX(FILTER(ROW('[IMPORTED] Database'!A:A), NOT(ISBLANK('[IMPORTED] Database'!A:A)))))`

Comment: This actually works, but it will be a bit of a hassle to do 'cause every now and then the Database spreadsheet keeps on updating and adding new rows, if I import it to my Checklist sheet, I have to keep importing it every time a new row has been added.

Comment: No. If you make a change in Database, it will automatically reflect in Checklist.

Comment: By "import" do you mean copy or move?

Comment: @L.Gold I don't quite understand your last question. All you need to do is use `IMPORTRANGE()` once. After you've done that, any time a change is made in Database, it will automatically show up Checklist because the `IMPORTRANGE()` function refreshes itself automatically.

Comment: @L.Gold I think I understand. Please see my revised answer as I detailed the steps for you.